# Ubuntu 20.04 does not start after update luks encrypted disk

Tags: boot, encryption, luks

The problem: A Dell notebook, after a recent update the system does not start any more. I'm tapping around the encrypted disk, or maybe its related to a graphics prlem. Normally, after getting through grub, I'm asked for the password to unlock the disk in some graphics mode. But now I'm not asked for the password, after switching to a graphical command line screen, it stops, the only thing I can do is pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del to restart the system.

The entire disk is Luks encrypted, except the boot partition:

`nvme0n1                  259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1              259:1    0   731M  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p2              259:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─nvme0n1p5              259:3    0 953,2G  0 part  
  └─myvolume             253:0    0 953,2G  0 crypt 
    ├─kubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 930,4G  0 lvm   /
    └─kubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0  15,6G  0 lvm`

What I tried so far: I started a live-stick, and I can mount the disk and change root:

`# sudo su
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p5 myvolume
# vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "kubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
# vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "kubuntu-vg" now active
# mount /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root /mnt/
# mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/
# for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
# chroot /mnt/`

I can reinstall grub, cryptsetup, intitramfs, aptitude upgrade, kernels, everything, but nothing helps. I can't find helpful messages in any of the logfiles, the only hint might be in one old syslog:

`Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 sddm[997]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 sddm[997]: Auth: sddm-helper crashed (exit code 15)
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 org.kde.kdeconnect[103919]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 ModemManager[936]:   ModemManager is shut down
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 org.kde.kglobalaccel[1237]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 sddm[997]: Authentication error: "Process crashed"
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 bluetoothd[826]: Terminating
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 sddm[997]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 15
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 bluetoothd[826]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 sddm[997]: Display server stopping...
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 bluetoothd[826]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 NetworkManager[832]:   [1645019656.2312] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Feb 16 14:54:16 ws-04 systemd1: Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...`

But I'm not sure if this is related to the problem.

Has anybode an idea, where I should focus to?

This post is hidden. It was deleted 4 hours ago by karel, Thomas Ward♦.

I just recognized, when selecting a recovery-mode option in Grub, after waiting long time (maybe one or two minutes), I get a message and in initramfs console:

`Begin: Running /script/local-premount ... findfs: unable to resolve "LABEL=writable"
done.
the required kernel command line snap_core is not set
BusyBox [...]
(initramfs)`

Update:

I learned a little about the initramfs console. Interestingly, I cannot find the disk in the console. Neither there is any /dev/mapper (except /dev/mapper/control), nor there is any /dev/disk, nor there is any /dev/nvme*. I reinstalled initramfs-tools and initramfs-cryptsetup and a couple of related packages via the live stick and going into the system with chroot as described above. No success. The disk seems to be fine, because I can decrypt and mount it with the live-stick...

**Update:**

I did something I don't know any more, but now I get some messages before falling into an initramfs console, when choosing a recovery mode kernel in Grub.

`Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-rot does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-2ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)`

According to [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589899/missing-modules-cat-proc-modules-ls-dev-and-uuid-doesnt-exist-in-busybox) you need to reinstall initramfs or change to another kernel version. But the point is, the problem is at all three kernel versions I have in the moment, 5.4.9-96-generic, -99- and -100-. Maybe the AHCI module ist missing int the initramfs, because I can not see any disk? How I could check/fix this?

Comment: It seems you are using DOS (MBR) partition table, have you made sure that nvme0n1p1 is been configured as active (bootable) partition? PS boot with a live-stick, open a terminal, enter `sudo parted`, select your disk with `select /dev/nvme0n1`, print stats about the table with `print free`, make sure you read `Partition Table: msdos`, enter `toggle 1 boot`, enter `print free` again, now there should a `boot` flag appear for partition 1 (if no boot flag appears, use `toggle 1 boot` again). Enter `quit`, and reboot your machine without the live-stick.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I had a look, but there is a boot flag when doing a frint free,

` 1      1049kB  768MB   767MB   primary   ext4          boot`

Answer (score 0):

The most productive hint came from a Windows-User, he asked "Isn't there a restore Point to go back to a working state?" Thereupon I searched for Aptitude Logfiles, maybe I can find out what was updated at the day when the system was still working. Indeed, in /var/log/ there are a couple of aptidude.x.gz files. I found that at that day the dracat was replaced by Initramfs. I tried to undo this step in the chroot mode. When marking dracut for installing, Aptitude made among other the following suggeston:

`Will install 5 packages, and remove 6 packages.
1124 kB of disk space will be used`


`[REMOVE, NOT USED] initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 0.136ubuntu6.7
[REMOVE, NOT USED] initramfs-tools-core:amd64 0.136ubuntu6.7
[REMOVE, NOT USED] klibc-utils:amd64 2.0.7-1ubuntu5
[REMOVE, NOT USED] libklibc:amd64 2.0.7-1ubuntu5
[REMOVE, NOT USED] lz4:amd64 1.9.2-2ubuntu0.20.04.1
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] dracut:amd64 048+80-2
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] dracut-core:amd64 048+80-2
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] finalrd:amd64 6~ubuntu20.04.1
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] kpartx:amd64 0.8.3-1ubuntu2
[INSTALL, DEPENDENCIES] mdadm:amd64 4.1-5ubuntu1.2
[REMOVE, DEPENDENCIES] initramfs-tools:amd64 0.136ubuntu6.7
Log complete.`

What looked promising for me. Indeed, I'm asked fot the Luks password at the beginning of boot, and the system starts normally.

So, now I'm afraid to make any updates, because it might replace dracat with initramfs again. I don't know what is the real problem, I guess, there is a bug in the cryptsetup-initramfs package. Is there any known issue?